# Why is PIVOT returning multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am on SQL 2k12 and stumbling with the PIVOT command.
My data looks like this

[source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c0vn.png)

I need the output like this

```
DimQuestion_y_attribute  [Q42] [Q13] [Q23]
Q14                      0.574 0.508 0.403
Q24                      0.117 0.19  0.111
```

The query I am using is this

```
    select DimQuestionNum_y_Attribute, [Q42],[Q13],[Q23]
from  [dbo].[Pearson_Coefficient_Values]
PIVOT 
(
 SUM(coeff_value) For DimQuestionNum_x_Rating IN ([Q42],[Q13],[Q23])
 ) p
 where surveyid = 1109245
```

The output I see is this

[current output does not match requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLTFD.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select DimQuestionNum_y_Attribute, [Q42],[Q13],[Q23]
from (select DimQuestionNum_y_Attribute,coeff_value, DimQuestionNum_x_Rating from   [dbo].[Pearson_Coefficient_Values]  where surveyid = 1109245) tb 
PIVOT 
(
 SUM(coeff_value) For DimQuestionNum_x_Rating IN ([Q42],[Q13],[Q23])
 ) p
```

Comment: sweet! that works...why does having other columns creating multiple rows?

Comment: i think its because of the where clause and also the official syntax suggests to use the sub-query

Comment: If you do a `select * `  with your original query, you will see that it is doing a PIVOT for all the columns on the table.

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative to PIVOT, you might want to try `SUM(CASE)` in some cases you will get better performance.

```
SELECT  DimQuestionNum_y_Attribute,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DimQuestionNum_x_Rating = 'Q42' THEN coeff_value END) [Q42],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DimQuestionNum_x_Rating = 'Q13' THEN coeff_value END) [Q13],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DimQuestionNum_x_Rating = 'Q23' THEN coeff_value END) [Q23]
FROM    [dbo].[Pearson_Coefficient_Values] 
WHERE   surveyid = 1109245
GROUP BY DimQuestionNum_y_Attribute
```